# Swift: printing to console variadic parameter of type Any

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code:

```
func log(items:Any...) {
...
for item in items {
      print(String(describing: item))
...
```

The output I get is surrounded by square brackets, as if I's printing a description of an array, for instance: `[Important stuff I wanna log]`
I don't exactly understand why would this happen. I could just trim parentheses, but I'm interested if there is a better way of doing it. Any help appreciated!

P.S.:
Silly of me to mention, but please don't offer me to just use `debugPrint`, or some popular logging pod - let's just say that's not an option

Comment: It's working for me: `log(items: "asd", 1, [1, 2, 3])` -> `asd\n1\n[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: Please post a full example of when this is happening and enough code so that it is reproducible

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was passing array of `[Any]` to the `log`. It's something like this:

```
private func log(_ items: Any...) {
...
for item in items {
  print(item)
 }
}

func logStuff(_ items: Any...) {
  log(items)
}
```

The function that I call is `logStuff`, which in turn calls the `log` function. The `log` function accepts a variadic parameter, however, the public function `logStuff` would give it one argument - items of type`[Any]`, as variadic parameters inside the function are just arrays. I changed the signature of `log` to `log(_ items: [Any])` so that it would reflect what's actually happening.
Thank you pawello2222 for quick reply.

Comment: Just note that the `log` function already exists: `public func log(_ x: Double) -> Double` - for logarithms. What will happen if you do `print(log(1.0))`? It might be better to remove the underscore from the signature of your function.

Comment: Nothing. My func is not a part of a public namespace, it's inside the enum.